# Reposting on Math.overflow which practice is best

Tags: discussion, mathoverflow, cross-posting

I just deleted a post of mine and reposted it on math.overflow. It was a question which was not very well received here it had 1 downvote and 2 upvotes and 1 favorite.

I followed the previous course of action after reading [Asking the same question on MSE and MO](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16288/asking-the-same-question-on-mse-and-mo), which was asked 3 years ago, and deciding I did not want to bother a moderator to migrate the question and since not a lot of people seemed interested in my question(in the sense it would be, supposedly, harder for people to the trace my question back to math.overflow).

Also, I had put a bounty on the question which was awarded back to me and felt a little bit like gaming the system as I was unaware previously that this would happen.

So, I think my question is when is it preferable to migrate over flagging for mods attention. And specifically should there was a bounty should you choose the migrating option? (I am also unaware whether if you migrate you obtain back your bounty which could potentially affect my view on the subject)

References: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2210786/probability-that-sde-visits-any-point (it is deleted so only available for 10k users)

*PS: I am asking this question after reposting only because of the bounty issue.*

Comment: Related to the issue about the returned bounty: [Reputation points from a bounty after deleting the question.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10439).

Comment: This might be also relevant to one of your questions: [What happens to a bounty question if it gets migrated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/38819) I found link to that post here: [Can a question with an open bounty on it be migrated from M.SE to MO?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11807)